# What is the difference between the /urlpage and urlpage?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I can't understand why sometimes a '/urlpage' is used over a simple 'urlpage'.

for example on a form,

```
<form action="TestServlet">

<form action="/TestServlet">
```

I want to understand what is the proper way of specifying a path to a html, servlet, jsp, jsf and etc.

Comment: "/" refers to the www root of the site. If you omit it, it refers to the relative position of current page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is relative to the current path. For example, if you are on /appcontext/abc/def/Something, TestServlet will be on /appcontext/abc/def/TestServlet

In the second one, it is relative to the context of your app: if you are on /appcontext/abc/def/Something, /TestServlet will be on /appcontext/TestServlet